# Fix latent variable endogenous variance (NOT residual variance) in Lavaan

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am fitting some models using lavaan. I have a number of latent variables (specifically I am fitting ACE behavioral genetics models with multiple phenotypes). For the model to be interpretable the latent variables need to have their variance constrained to 1. My model also regresses some latent variables on other latent variables. Lavaan (and most other software) makes it trivially easy to constrain exogenous latent variable variances and endogenous latent variable residuals to 1 (or any other number), but I haven't found a good way to constrain the endogenous latent variable variance itself. I understand that this isn't frequently done in SEM because typically the latent variable metric is relatively unimportant/not interpreted, but in this case it would be extremely useful.

Edit:
A basic version of the model would be this:

LV1=~V1+V2

LV2=~V3+V4

LV1~~1*LV1

LV2~~1*LV2

LV2~LV1

The portion that is causing difficulty is "LV2~~1*LV2" I would like to be constraining the total variability of LV2 to be 1, but lavaan (and Mplus etc) interprets that constraint as being on the residual variance of LV2, not on the total variance.

Comment: Does this tutorial help constrain the desired variances? http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax2.html

Comment: @jsk No, that tutorial shows how to constrain the model parameters, but when the constraints are applied to endogenous latent variable variances it is applied to the residual variance, not the total variance.

Comment: Can you add an equation to your post that makes it explicit what your model is and which variance you are trying to constrain?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't possible to fit the full model without constraints. Generally speaking an ACE model is underidentified without those constraints. The issue here is that the model is identified with the constraint, but I think the results aren't really interpretable since the constraint is on the residual variance and these models generally are interpreted with the constraint that the variance of the latent variable be 1.

Comment: It looks LV2~ LV1 may actually report a regression coefficient of LV1 on LV2. You can get the regression coefficient reported by dividing the covariance between LV1 and LV2 (in the model without the regression) by var(LV2) again from model without regression assuming you did not use std.lv=T. Also, just to be clear, do you want to set Var(lv2)=1 rather than Var(lv2 | lv1)=1?

Comment: You are correct that LV2~LV1 is a regression, and yes I want Var(lv2)=1. However I'm not sure that simply taking the covariances will give the same results. It would for the model posted above, but that was drastically simplified. A more complete model would look something like this:

LV1=~V1+V2;

LV2=~V3+V4;

LV3=~V5+V6;

LV1~~1*LV1;

LV2~~1*LV2;

LV3~~1*LV3;

LV2~LV1;

LV3~LV1+LV2;

i.e. a mediated regression of latent variables. There are up to three sets of mediation analyses in a single model, and all latent variables need to have total variances of 1.